# Permutation matrix homomorphism

Tags: matrices, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-matrices

Can someone please help me prove that permutation matrix is homomorphism? By that, I mean, let $f: S_n \to GL_n (\Bbb R), f(\sigma)=A_\sigma$ is homomorphism. The book tells me to prove it myself I have no idea how to. A small hint would do

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Recent question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715759/product-of-permutation-matrices-is-the-matrix-of-the-composition

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that, for all $\sigma_1, \sigma_2\in S_n$, 
$$
f(\sigma_1\sigma_2)=f(\sigma_1)f(\sigma_2).
$$
In your case, this means

$$A_{\sigma_1\sigma_2}=A_{\sigma_1}A_{\sigma_2}.$$

Comment: thats clear from definition. Can you pls elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I think the point is that you should try to prove the statement by going to the actual definition and writing things out.  What is the definition of the permutation matrices?  What is the definition of matrix multiplication? You will have to do a small computation, and the point is that you don't need any big ideas, just the definitions of everything involved.

Comment: @Aaron I solved it. I just panicked somehow, thanks :D computational stuff scares me

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton I always spend too much time looking for a high level conceptual perspective that I sometimes overlook easy computations.  But for simple problems, going to definitions and doing simple calculations can be quite effective.  Unfortunately, it can be hard to tell what is simple until after you have solved it.